# Webview not showing changing focus between its elements

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-tv

I am building a Android TV app.
So added a Webview to show my webpage in the app, but it is not showing changing focus between its elements.
Below is my Webview in xml:

```
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

and below is my properties of Webview in my Java file:

```
    webView=findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.MyUrl.com");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.requestFocus();
    webView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
    webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN| View.FOCUS_UP);
```

Comment: send screen shot

Comment: screenshot of what?

Comment: ut it is not showing changing focus between its elements.this ...

Comment: i cant send screenshot . but i can tell i.e it is scrolling down and up by arrow keys but not showing focus change

Comment: Are you referring to the ["View focus"](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#focus) mentioned in the documentation? Isn't the reason that it acts that way because of the behavioral change?